# Is it reasonable to try and fix these kernel boot lags?

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel

I've noticed the bootup process pauses for a while. Can I fix this? Is it even worth trying? This system used to boot up faster.

uname -rp:

```
4.19.25-041925-generic x86_64
```

(I actually rolled back from 4.20.12 but there it took even longer.)

dmesg:

```
...

[    5.532700] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    5.556565] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    9.405339] ata1.00: qc timeout (cmd 0x47)
[    9.407728] ata1.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying PIO
[    9.407737] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[    9.407742] ata1.00: ATA-10: FORESEE 128GB SSD, V3.15, max UDMA/133

...

[   18.675961] wlp1s0: associated
[   19.020500] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[   29.000586] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   29.000597] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   29.000610] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   31.806813] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

Comment: What version Ubuntu?

Comment: It is 18.04.2 LTS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: You're using an unsupported kernel. 4.19 is known to corrupt file systems. Put the standard kernel back.

From what little log detail that you left for us to review, it looks like you might be getting NCQ errors on your disk. You might look at this more closely to see if there are a bunch more NCQ errors...

`sudo grep -i ncq /var/log/syslog*` # search for NCQ errors

If you find a bunch, then...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit the grub settings

Find the line near the top that says "quiet splash", and change it to read...

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"`

Save the file and then...

`sudo update-grub` # update grub files

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would be rude to have the full log in the question. Here it is now. https://pastebin.com/x2pWgDRX

Comment: I have disabled NCQ (I don't even know what it is) but the startup does not become quicker.

Comment: I tried to change the kernel because my laptop touchpad wasn't supported by what I had by default. I used ukuu to do so.

Comment: Then I'd remove the noncq kernel parameter. Kernel 4.19 shows "Speculative Store Bypass: Vulnerable" so you could catch something, and it's known to corrupt filesystems... go back to a supported kernel.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, how do I know if it is supported? Supported by what: by Ubuntu or by my hardware?

Comment: @HorseWeakness Please clarify your question... supported? What, kernel, ncq, speculative?

Comment: 'go back to a supported kernel': the question was, what 'supported' meant here!

Comment: If a 'supported kernel' means what I had bundled with 18.04.2 LTS, the problem is, I will lose my touchpad support if I go back to it.

Comment: @HorseWeakness You might boot a Ubuntu Live 18.10 DVD/USB and see if your touchpad works there.

Comment: @HorseWeakness fyi: ncq is "native command queuing"... Native Command Queuing is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed. Some drives don't support ncq, hence the noncq parameter.

Comment: That is great! There is an SSD here, therefore NCQ does not sound like a necessary thing. Hopefully there is no swap on the drive, by the way. I will check it. Thank you for the information.